# add 'success' message to html form

Tags: wordpress, forms

I have an HTML form I'm custom coding that integrates with a drip (email platform) form. And I'm trying to get it to show a "success" message (e.g. "thank you for signing up to our newsletter".

What would be the best/cleanest way be to adapt the HTML to allow that message after a submit action?

Here's my code so far:

```
  <form class="subscribe-form" form action="https://www.getdrip.com/forms/0123456789/submissions" method="post" data-drip-embedded-form="0123456789">
    <div style="width:25vw">
      <input class="subscribe-form__input" type="email" id="drip-email" name="fields[email]" placeholder="Email" value="" >
    </div>

        <button class="subscribe-form__submit" type="submit" data-drip-attribute="sign-up-button">Sign Up</button>

  </form>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start off by creating the message and styling it properly. Maybe something like this...

```
<form class="subscribe-form" form action="https://www.getdrip.com/forms/0123456789/submissions" method="post" data-drip-embedded-form="0123456789">
        <div style="width:25vw">
          <input class="subscribe-form__input" type="email" id="drip-email" name="fields[email]" placeholder="Email" value="" >
        </div>

            <button class="subscribe-form__submit" type="submit" data-drip-attribute="sign-up-button">Sign Up</button>

</form>

<p class="subscribe-form__thanks">Thanks for subscribing!</p>
```

You could even wrap the thank you in a `div` if you would like and add a "thumbs up" icon to fill the space.

Once you're happy with your design, add this to you CSS (if you're using SASS/SCSS, you can add it nested within the element):

```
hide {
    display: none;
}
```

and add that class to your "Thank You" message, like this:

```
   <p class="subscribe-form__thanks hide">Thanks for subscribing!</p>
```

Now that that's all set up, you simply need to use JavaScript to remove the `hide` class from the "Thank You" message, and add it to the form, which will reveal the message and hide the form.

I'll use JQuery for brevity, but Vanilla JS will work great too!

```
$(".subscribe-form__submit").onClick(()=>{
   $(".subscribe-form").addClass("hide");
   $(".subscribe-form__thanks").removeClass("show");
});
```

That should all be working as desired - the form should disappear and the message should appear! The animation could be a little jarring, so have a play around with fading then hiding, and matching the height of the two divs to avoid the page having to change size.

This will hide the form, even if the fields are incorrect/incomplete, so you could look into validate.js to improve your usability if you're interested.

**NOTE**: This method of using the `onClick()` JQuery selector doesn't guarantee that the user is actually subscribed to the mailing list - your Drip API request could be incorrect, or their API could fail/be offline.

You can look into the Drip API's callback function (https://developer.drip.com/) if you're interested in making sure the user is properly subscribed, however there's no guarantee they will reply in a timely fashion, and so you'd most likely be over complicating things.

Hope this helped!!